# Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.maven.apache.org

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm a freshman for the spring framework. I generate project from start.spring.io and now I try to run it.
when I try it, I have to face following exception,
(I use TomCat server)
plz..give solution for this,

===========================Exception=============================

```
G:\courses\Course-projects\spring-projects\S5Guru\spring5webapp>mvnw spring-boot:run
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.maven.apache.org
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.downloadInternal(DefaultDownloader.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.download(DefaultDownloader.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.Installer.createDist(Installer.java:72)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Comment: Can you confirm your internet is working?

Comment: I assume you are trying to access it via http instead of https ....

Comment: I had the same problem :(. My network is being worked behind the proxy server. Is anybody help me?

Answer (score 5):

This problem occurs when there's a proxy server, e.g. in a company network. To solve this, create file HOME/.mvn/jvm.config with this content:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy-server>
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyUser=<user>
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=<password>
-Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy-server>
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyUser=<user>
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=<password>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same probleme, it was my Internet Provider's fault, their DNS server could not resolve `repo.maven.apache.org`.

I switched to 4G internet connection and it's worked.

Comment: After spending 3.5 hours on local repository and remote repository settings, I fixed problem with your answer. Than you so much for the information.

Answer (score -1):

Having working internet connection if necessary for this.

Comment: Internet connection is working. it is a 4G connection, I change it into 3G, then spring-boot worked. What is the problem using 4G Connection?